# How to clear this push_back() segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault, breadth-first-search

I have a vector of type < Vertex*>*, and a variable k of type Vertex*. When I try to push back k in this vector v, there's a segfault(core dumped). Any idea what could be causing this? Here's the code, if it helps.

My code is basically a BFS graph search to find the shortest path between 2 vertices.

```
queue<Vertex*> myqueue;
unordered_map<Vertex*,Vertex*> mymap;
std::vector<Vertex*>* v;
//std::vector<Vertex*>* d;
Vertex* k;
Vertex* f;
Vertex* l;
//here I will store the visited vertices(ones that've been put into the queue.) as well as the the previous nodes of this unordered map.

if(!containsVertex(v1)||!containsVertex(v2))
{
    cout<<"The vertices you wish to find the shortest path between, don't exist. You might want to check them."<<endl;
    return NULL;
}

myqueue.push(v1);
mymap[v1]=NULL;
cout<<"Pushed v1"<<endl;
while(!myqueue.empty())
{
    cout<<"Entered while loop"<<endl;
    f=myqueue.front();
    myqueue.pop();

    cout<<"executed popping"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<neighbors(f).size();i++)
    {
        cout<<"entered for loop"<<endl;
        if(neighbors(f).at(i)==v2)
        {
            cout<<"found the guy. Preparing to output the vector"<<endl;
            k=v2;
            mymap[v2]=f;
            cout<<"Is the fault here?"<<endl;
            while(mymap[k]!=v1)
            {
                cout<<"Entered the while loop"<<endl;
                v->push_back(k);
                cout<<"After the pushback?"<<endl;
                cout<<v->size()<<endl;
                cout<<"After outputting the size?"<<endl;
                l=mymap[k];
                cout<<"After the mapping retrieval?"<<endl;
                k=l;
                cout<<"after the end assignment?"<<endl;
            }
            cout<<"Exited the while loop"<<endl;
            v->push_back(v1);
            return v;
        }
        if(mymap.find(neighbors(f).at(i))==mymap.end())
        {
            myqueue.push(neighbors(f).at(i));
            mymap[neighbors(f).at(i)]=f;
        }
    }
}
cout<<"There doesn't exist a shortest path between these two vertices."<<endl;
return NULL;
```

The seg fault arises during the part where I try to start pushing the elements in the vector.

Comment: So, you only want to clear the indicator, not fix the bug? Anyway, need a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you have:

```
std::vector<Vertex*>* v;
// bunch of lines that don't reference v
v->push_back(k);
```

At no point does `v` point to an actual object. You need an actual vector to push_back onto. Either:

```
std::vector<Vertex*>* v = new std::vector<Vertex*>;
// remember to delete it
```

Or, do you really need the pointer?

```
std::vector<Vertex*> v;
// bunch of lines
v.push_back(k);
```

Answer (score 1):

You never assign `v`, which is a pointer to a vector (of pointers...) on the heap. This is why you're segfaulting.

Before using v, adding something like will fix your immediate problem:

```
v = new std::vector<Vertex*>;
```

Aside from that mistake, you may want to consider walking through your design and deciding if this type of data structure makes sense. As others have pointed out, an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example would let us understand better what you're trying to do.

That said, defining a raw pointer to a vector containing raw pointers is likely not what you want to do. Without looking to hard at your code, changing v to a locally scoped (on your stack) vector is probably up for the task

```
std::vector<Vertex*> v;
```

(and then change all `v->` to `v.`